# How to add element to List inside MutableLiveData

Tags: list, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

The .add() function is not working. I have tried changing the List to MutableList in both places, and it gives me a type error?

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _shoes = MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>(listOf(
        Shoe("Air Jordan", 6.0, "Nike", "Michael Jordan's Finest Shoe")
    ))

    val shoes: LiveData<List<Shoe>> = _shoes

    fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe){

    }

}
```

Update:

Tried changing to mutable list, and it would only allow me to do so without a type error if I used .toMutableList() after or cast it as an expression. E.g.

```
        private val _shoes = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>(
        listOf(
            Shoe("Air Jordan", 6.0, "Nike", "Michael Jordan's Finest Shoe")
        ).toMutableList()
    )
```

OR:

```
    private val _shoes = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>(
        listOf(
            Shoe("Air Jordan", 6.0, "Nike", "Michael Jordan's Finest Shoe")
        ) as MutableList<Shoe>?
    )
```

Both of these do not allow me to use .add() function still. Is .add definitely the function that I want to use, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Edit 2:

Have updated & converted to mutableListOf(), and shown the syntax that I was using. The LiveData should register the change as I observe it after the change in another fragment I believe.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _shoes = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>(
        mutableListOf(
        Shoe("Air Jordan", 6.0, "Nike", "Michael Jordan's Finest Shoe")
    )
    )

    val shoes: LiveData<MutableList<Shoe>> = _shoes

    fun addShoe (shoe: Shoe){
        _shoes.add(shoe)
    }
}
```

Comment: `List` is read-only and not directly mutable. Search for `MutableList`.

Comment: `MutableList` wouldn't give you a type error here, feel free to post that version so we can point out your mistake.

Comment: Have updated @HenryTwist, I did also update the other variable "shoes" to use a MutableList also.

Comment: Use `mutableListOf()` instead of `listOf()` so you won’t have to convert it with `toMutableList()` or cast it. How are you trying to use the `add()` function? It should work fine so your syntax must be wrong. However, the LiveData won’t automatically register the change because it won’t know that the list contents are changing. It’s easier/cleaner to use read-only Lists and just creat new lists that you assign to the LiveData.

Comment: Have updated & converted to mutableListOf(), and shown the syntax that I was using. The LiveData should register the change as I observe it after the change in another fragment I believe. @Tenfour04

Comment: You have to add to the List that is inside the LiveData. Also, you have to set the list on the LiveData for it to register the change. So it should be `_shoes.value?.apply { add(shoe); _shoes.value = this }` But I think it's simpler to use `MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>`, and instead of adding to the List, you create a new one. Then your `addShoe` function would look like: `_shoes.value = _shoes.value!! + shoe`.

Comment: The LiveData won't register any change because the list instance is the same. There's no way a LiveData will know you called add() on the list instance it is wrapping. You need to pass a NEW list instance for it to register a change (it also won't register a change if you pass the same instance but I'm not sure this has changed with newer versions).

Comment: @m0skit0 It does register as a change if you call `setValue` with the same instance it is already referencing.